# Avoid skipping elements in xml reader

Tags: c#, xml

Let's suppose that I have a xml like this:

```
<articles>
  <article>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>A1</name>
    <price>10</price>
  </article>
  <article>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>A2</name>
   </article>
  <article>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>A3</name>
    <price>30</price>
  </article>
</articles>
```

As you can see article A2 is missing price tag.

I have a real world case where I parse xml file where some tags in some articles are missing (which I didn't know earlier). I wrote a very simple parser like this:

```
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(myXml)))
     {
     while (true)
       {
        bool articleExists = reader.ReadToFollowing("article");
        if (!articleExists) return;

        reader.ReadToFollowing("id");
        string id = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        reader.ReadToFollowing("name");
        string name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        reader.ReadToFollowing("price");
        string price = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        //do something with these values
     }
```

But if there is no price tag in article 2 xmlreader will jump to price tag in article A3 and I get articles mixed up and some data skipped, right?

How can I protect from this? So if some tag in article node is absent, then let's say default value is used?

I would still like to use xmlreader if possible. My real file is 200 MB big so I need a simple,fast and efficient solution that won't hang the system.

Comment: Create a class and use the `XmlSerialzer` class, should handle it all for you. I believe you can even get Visual Studio to create the class for you, all though I'm not sure how.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder this tool can do it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use XmlSerialzer or use some DOM methods like GetElementsByTagName  and "get child by name" and you won't have those problems.